# how to dynamically calculate value in the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have a invoice where i have to calculate some value in the textbox using jquery.

I don't know much about Jquery. Please help me to solve this problem.

In my invoice there is quantity textbox,

> if users enters the quantity then dynamically it should  show the
>   calculated price i.e `(total_subPrice= unit_price * quantity)` in
>   another textbox called "price".

And again the total sum of all the price should be visible in the button as a Total.

please check my below html code and run it in browser then you will understand my problem exactly.

```
             <html>
        <body>
        <form name="invoice form" action="saveToDatabase.java">
        <table border="1" height="30%" width="30%">
        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5">Customer Invoice</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="5%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Sn.no.</td>
            <td width="25%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Item</td>
            <td width="25%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Unit Price(In $)</td>
            <td width="20%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Quantity</td>
            <td width="25%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Line Total<br/>(Price * Qnty)</td>  
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="5%">1</td>
            <td width="25%">Iphone 5S</td>
            <td width="25%"><input type="text" value="400" name="unitprice1" size="4" disabled></td>
            <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="quantity1" value="2" size="2"/></td>
            <td width="25%"><input type="text" name="price1" value="400" size="4"/></td>  
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="5%">2</td>
            <td width="25%">Ipad 2</td>
            <td width="25%"><input type="text" value="700" name="unitprice2" size="4" disabled></td>
            <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="quantity2" value="1" size="2"/></td>
            <td width="25%"><input type="text" name="price2=" value="700" size="4"/></td>  
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="5%">1</td>
            <td width="25%">mp3</td>
            <td width="25%"><input type="text" value="50" name="unitprice1" size="4" disabled></td>
            <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="quantity1" value="3" size="2"/></td>
            <td width="25%"><input type="text" name="price1" value="150" size="4"/></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="5">Total<input type="text" name="subtotal" value="1250" size="12" disabled/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form></body>
        </html>
```

Comment: your html doesn't hav a body tag even though you are using html as a parent tag.

Comment: what you are doing in .java file?

Comment: @Jai Okay i edited. Please help me to solve my problem...

Comment: @joeyrohan in my .java file, i will save all these values into my database using some java code.. Just i have doubt in frontend. How to calculate the values..

Comment: you should give the result, I cannot understand what is going on here, I see some values, I can only say, use parseInt() to sum values

Comment: i have given the result.. run my code into the browser... You will understand.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoy seeing practical examples to learn stuff like jQuery myself, so I made an example for your problem so you can see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/LGyeq/

Line by line:

Select all of the input tags and call a function if they are changed:

```
$('input').change(function(){
```

create a variable to store the totals, to calculate the subtotal:

```
var linetotals = 0;
```

select each element with class 'lineTotal' (which I added, so that we could select them):

```
$('.lineTotal').each(function(){
```

Get price and quantity by finding the input elements within the same tr element (eq(#) gets the first and second element respectively):

```
price = $(this).parents('tr').find('input').eq(0).val();
quantity = $(this).parents('tr').find('input').eq(1).val();
```

Set the lineTotal class element to the new total, and add the total to lineTotals variable:

```
$(this).val(price*quantity);
linetotals += price*quantity;
```

});

Set the subtotal to the value of the linetotals variable:

```
    $('#total').val(linetotals);
});​
```

This is one way you can do it.  It has a lot to do with preference.  Hope this is a good start.

### Update

Re: Askers new request for more generalized code

Use CSS Attribute selectors to select the input fields.  JSFiddle is updated with the following code:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    var linetotals = 0;
    $('[name^="price"]').each(function(){
        price = $(this).parents('tr').find('input').eq(0).val();
        quantity = $(this).parents('tr').find('input').eq(1).val();
        $(this).val(price*quantity);
        linetotals += price*quantity;
    });
    $('[name=subtotal]').val(linetotals);
});​
```

Comment: this works fine. But my page is in jsp Struts2(Java framework). I want to solve my problem using id of textbox. You have used `$('input').change(function(){` instead of that some  input field id should be use. And also the number of rows in my form will be dynamic i.e users may select many item to buy. Currently i am showing only 3 items in my above html code. There may be 20 item also.    Please provide some another way to solve this problem. I guess you understand my problem.

Comment: I don't understand.  My code works for any number of rows.  Using an input field id, as you say, will make it less able to handle more data.

Comment: in my jsp page i write `<s:textfield name="quantity" value="%{quantity}" size="2" />` instead of `<input type="text" name="quantity1" value="2" size="2"/>`  . and these item values are comming from my database dynamically based on users selection of item.

Comment: @Ashutosh To make it MORE general, use CSS attribute selectors: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors;

See updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/LGyeq/;

I used `[name=subtotal]` for the subtotal, for example.

Comment: new doubt , i also want 1 textbox at the button before showing the total. Text field name "discount". If users enter the discount price then again the total price should reflact `i.e total = all price sum + discount amount`

Comment: @Ashutosh that should be easy enough to figure out. I mean, you have the code there pretty much.  `discount = $('[name=discount]').val()` and `$('[name=subtotal]').val(linetotals-discount);`. Good luck.

Comment: Now i am implementing your jquery code for html tags into my jsp page. I hope this will work. If it works then i will "select your answer as correct" Nor i will ask you again. You already shown me running example show i should not ask much with you. Thankyou